# Binding multiple comboboxes with a name list in a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, tkinter, combobox, bind

I'm designing a GUI to decrease the time which my colleagues spend for reporting tests. I planned multiple comboboxes for the tests. After choices are made I want to collect them in a dictionary composed of determined names and choices. I managed the bind the names to the dictionary but values:
Archieve={"Jane":StringVar, "Lily":StringVar "Harry":StringVar, "John":StringVar}
I tried both binding and tracing methods but the this is the best result I could get. What do you suggest?
PS: I don't know how to use Class methods.
Here is my simplified code (I didn't want to confuse your mind with medical tests, all I need is combine the exam results with student names in the dictionary named "Archieve"):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg="white")

Students=["Jane", "Lily", "Harry", "John"]
Options=["No Data", "Passed", "Failed"]
Archieve={}

def SAVE(var):
    global Name
    Archieve[Name]=var

for i in range(len(Students)):
    Name=Students[i]
    tk.Label(root, text=Name, bg="white").grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    var = tk.StringVar()
    Combobox4=ttk.Combobox(root, value=Options, textvariable=var)
    Combobox4.current(0)
    Combobox4.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", SAVE(Name, var))
    var.trace("w", SAVE(Name, var))
    Combobox4.grid(row=i+1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `Combobox4.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", SAVE(Name, var))` to `Combobox4.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda e, Name=Name, var=var: SAVE(Name, var))` and `var.trace("w", SAVE(Name, var))` to `var.trace("w", lambda *_, Name=Name, var=var: SAVE(Name, var))`

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer TheLizzard but still the same. I changed my code as follows:
def SAVE(var):
    Archieve[Name]=var
for i in range(len(Students)):
    Name=Students[i]
    tk.Label(root, text=Name, bg="white").grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    var = tk.StringVar()
    Combobox4=ttk.Combobox(root, value=Options, textvariable=var)
    Combobox4.current(0)
    Combobox4.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda e, Name=Name, var=var: SAVE(Name, var))
    var.trace("w", lambda *_, Name=Name, var=var: SAVE(Name, var))
    Combobox4.grid(row=i+1, column=1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the student name and the selected option to `SAVE()` function whenever one of the combobox value is changed:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg="white")

Students=["Jane", "Lily", "Harry", "John"]
Options=["No Data", "Passed", "Failed"]
# initialize Archieve dictionary
Archieve={name:Options[0] for name in Students}

def SAVE(Name, val):
    Archieve[Name]=val
    print(Archieve)

for i, Name in enumerate(Students):
    tk.Label(root, text=Name, bg="white").grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    Combobox4=ttk.Combobox(root, value=Options)
    Combobox4.grid(row=i+1, column=1)
    Combobox4.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda e,name=Name: SAVE(name,e.widget.get()))
    Combobox4.current(0)

root.mainloop()
```

Note that tkinter variables are not used.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much acw1668, it works! Just one last question: If I want to use my dictionary with different lists, is it enough to use *args? It doesn't matter, I can use different dictionaries to store my data but I want to learn the correct way.

Comment: In my original program there will be five or six name list (instead of Students). How can I use the SAVE function to bind all lists to my dictionary (here Archieve). I can use multiple dictionaries and then update them to one main dictionary but is there any easy (or correct) way?

Comment: `SAVE()` function accepts `name` and `val` arguments, so you can use on other list basically.

Comment: But Archieve only recognizes the Students, how can I cahnge it to multiple?
Archieve={name:Options[0] for name in Students}

Comment: You can use dictionary of dictionaries, like `{"student": {...}, "others": {...}}`.

Comment: It seems that all my problems are solved, acw1668 thank you!